# Iterate and compare unknown amount of input in Python

Tags: python, recursion, set, arguments, argv

The following snippet takes two arguments, compares the values contained therein and prints any matches.

```
from sys import argv

print(set(argv[1]) & set(argv[2]))
#Output: python multicompare.py man fan
#{'n', 'a'}
```

How would one adapt this to deal with an unknown and potentially unlimited (or very large) amount of arguments? I tried iterating over the arguments and passing them to a function, but without having a known amount of arguments, how can I call set() against them all and reference them?
What's expected:

```
#Output: python3 multicompare.py man fan dan tan han
# {'n', 'a'}
#Output: python3 multicompare.py man fan dan can fin tin mountain happen trappen
# {'n'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over `sys.argv` and use `&=` operator. If you call this with arguments `man fan dan can fin tin mountain happen trappen`:

```
import sys

s = set(sys.argv[1])

for a in sys.argv[2:]:
    s &= set(a)

print(s)
```

Then it prints:

```
{'n'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) method of [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)s, you don't actually need to convert the arguments to sets (well, that is except one).

> the non-operator version[s] of ... [intersection()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) ... method[s]
>   will accept any iterable as an argument. In contrast, their operator
>   based counterparts require their arguments to be sets.

So you could do something like:

```py
import sys

print(set(sys.argv[1]).intersection(*sys.argv[2:]))
```